# How to access an attribute of an arbitrary element of a set

Tags: python, set

I have a non-empty set `S` and every `s in S` has an attribute `s.x` which I know is independent of the choice of `s`. I'd like to extract this common value `a=s.x` from `S`. There is surely something better than

```
s=S.pop()
a=s.x
S.add(s)
```

-- maybe that code is fast but surely I shouldn't be changing `S`?

Clarification: some answers and comments suggest iterating over all of `S`. The reason I want to avoid this is that `S` might be huge; my method above will I think run quickly however large `S` is; my only issue with it is that `S` changes, and I see no reason that I need to change `S`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're going for, but could something like `[x.x for x in S]` work?

Comment: Sure that would work (and then I could just just take the 0th element of that list), but what if `S` has a million elements? Why iterate over all of them when the answer is in the first one I find? Note that `s.x` is the same for every element `s` of `S`.

Comment: You're right, wasn't exactly sure what you were going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost but not quite the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625579/python-access-the-sole-element-of-a-set) on getting access to an element of a set when there's only one-- there are solutions which apply there which won't work here, and others which work but are inefficient. But the general trick of using `next(iter(something_iterable))` to nondestructively get an element still applies:

```
>>> S = {1+2j, 2+2j, 3+2j}
>>> next(iter(S))
(2+2j) # Note: could have been any element
>>> next(iter(S)).imag
2.0
```