# How to reduce the sets in dict values using comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iterable-unpacking, functools

I have

```
x = {'a':set([1]) , 'b':set([2]), 'c':set([3]) }
```

It is guaranteed that there is only one element in the set. I need to convert this to

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Following works:

```
x1 = {k:x[k].pop() for k in x.keys()}  OR
x1 = {k:next(iter(x[k])) for k in x.keys()}
```

but I am not liking it as `pop()` here is modifying the original collection. I need help on following.

- How can I use unpacking as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22693614/2373278)  within comprehension.
- Is there any way, I can use `functools.reduce` for this.
- What can be a better or Pythonic way of doing this overall?

Comment: `functools.reduce` has pretty much nothing to do with the operation you're trying to perform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this with an unpacking, that'd be

```
{k: item for k, [item] in x.iteritems()}
```

Comment: This will produce an `AttributeError` within `Python 3.5.2`.

Comment: @ChihebNexus: Indeed it will, but the question is tagged 2.7.

Comment: Thanks for this. That's what I wanted. Just to mention for other, unpacking also performs the validation that there is only one element in set which is the case here. unpacking on elements with more than one elements will give an error.

Comment: `{k: item for k, [item] in x.items()}` would be the way to do it someone is looking for the version compatible with Python 2 as well as 3. `items` is inefficient in Python 2 but for small lists shouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the most readable option would be to use `next` and `iter`. <strike>Unpacking might also not be of much use since it is more of an assignment operation.</strike> (See user2357112's answer)

How about simply:

```
>>> {k: next(iter(v)) for k, v in x.items()}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```