# What is the time complexity of dict.keys() in Python?

Tags: python

I came across a question when I solved [this LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1/). Although my solution got accepted by the system, I still do not have any idea after searching online for the following question:

`What is the time complexity of dict.keys() operation?`

Does it return a view of the keys or a real list (stores in memory) of the keys?

Comment: It's complexity is `0(1)` in Python 3.x. In Python 2.x, it returns a list so populating it or performing some lookup on it takes `0(n)`.

Comment: Are you asking about Python2 or Python3?

Comment: @ozgur - True, but `for _ in {}.keys(): pass` is `O(n)` in either version.

Comment: @Robᵩ that's true but I think OP is asking about the cost of calling `.keys()`, not iterating over that.

Comment: @Robᵩ I use Python 2. Is there any difference between Python 2.x and 3.x?

Comment: Yes. As @ozgur points out, merely calling `dict.keys()` and not doing anything with the result is `O(n)` in Python2 and `O(1)` in Python3.

Comment: @ozgur Yep. I am asking about the cost of calling .keys(), not iterating over that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Python 2, it's O(n), and it builds a new list. In Python 3, it's O(1), but it doesn't return a list. To draw a random element from a dict's `keys`, you'd need to convert it to a list, and that conversion is O(n).

It sounds like you were probably using `random.choice(d.keys())` for part 3 of that problem. If so, that was O(n), and you got it wrong. You need to either implement your own hash table or maintain a separate list of elements, without sacrificing average-case O(1) insertions and deletions.

Comment: I used `return self.elements.keys()[randint(0, len(self.elements) - 1)]` and it got accepted (`self.elements is a dict object`).

Comment: @Jason: Yeah, that's not O(1).

Comment: As you said "In Python 3, it's O(1)". If `self.elements.keys()` is `O(1)`, then the whole expression would run in`O(1)`. If I made mistakes, please correct me:)

Comment: @Jason: `dict.keys()` is set-like in Python 3; you can't draw a random element from it without converting it to a list or tuple or something.

Comment: If `self.elements.keys()` is set-like, then how does the index operation `return self.elements.keys()[randint(0, len(self.elements) - 1)]`  work? Will the set-like 'object' be converted to list object automatically?

Comment: @Jason: "how does the index operation ... work" - it doesn't. On Python 3, you get a TypeError.

Comment: @Jason, in Python3, you would get `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing`

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `random.choice` - Didn't know about it and saved a lot of time for me now!

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a O(n) time to build dictionary.keys() in Python 3.10:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
t = []
N = 24
total = 2**N
for i in range(10,N):
    numbers = list(np.random.choice(total,2**i,replace=False))
    d = {x:x for x in numbers}
    # ---- Start timer ----
    starttime = timeit.default_timer()
    keys = d.keys()
    took = timeit.default_timer() - starttime
    # ---- End timer ------
    del starttime
    x.append(2**i)
    t.append(took)

plt.clf()
plt.scatter(x[1:], t[1:])
plt.title("Time taken to construct dictionary.keys()")
plt.xlabel("Size of the dictionary with random keys")
plt.ylabel("Time [s]")
plt.show()
```

Look at this plot:

[image: Look at this plot]

Comment: That's not the time taken to construct `d.keys()`. That's the time taken to perform the cleanup triggered when the old dict is rendered unreachable.

Comment: When you reassign `keys`, you remove the last reference to the old view object, which itself owned the last reference to the old dict, and that dict owned the only references to a large number of NumPy array scalars. Cleaning up all that takes time proportional to the size of the old dict.