# What is the time complexity of converting a Python dict.keys() in Set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, time-complexity

As I found in many posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219065/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-dict-keys-in-python) and others sources of the Internet [like this](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/13702734.html), in Python 3 the method `keys()` for dictionaries, returns something like a `memoryview` object, this makes this operation able to run in a constant time complexity `O(1)`.

Since `dict.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object instead a `list` object which have a `O(n)` when doing the operation `set(some_list_obj)`, what is the Time Complexity of `set(some_dict_keys_obj])`?

**Note:** I realized that doing `set(some_dict_obj)` returns a set with the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: I'd expect it to be `O(n)`, as it'll iterate over the view (unless it's been special-cased somewhere).

Comment: The source code is on GitHub if you want to read it: [setobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c)

Answer (score 0):

Since the time complexity of dict.keys() is `O(1)`, the only time complexity you need to consider would be when iterating through the dict.keys(), which would be `O(n)`.